# Pegar parâmetro com Slim Framework 3

Tags: php, slim

Preciso de ajuda para pegar o parâmetro `id` no momento em que a URI é chamada, passando o mesmo para o `container`.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
$this->get('/{id}', function($request, $response, $args) {
  return $response->withJson($this->get('singleSelect'));
});

$this->appContainer['singleSelect'] = function ($id) {
  return $this->singleSelect($id);
};

public function singleSelect($id) {
  return $id;
}
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o problema do seu código é chamar a variável que recebe o objeto \Slim\App() de $this. Ou seja: pelo que vi você fez: `$this = new \Slim\App();` quando deveria ter chamado a variável de $app ou outra qualquer mas de menos uma palavra reservada como o $this, exemplo:

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
```

Fiz o teste com o código abaixo e funcionou normalmente:

```
<?php

use \Slim\App;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

// Create app
$app = new \Slim\App();

// Get container
$container = $app->getContainer();


$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) {
echo "Slim Framework";
});

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->withJson('Name: ' . $args['name']
    );
});

$app->get('/hello', function ($request, $response){
    echo "Ola";
});

$app->get('/{id}', function($request, $response, $args) {
  return $response->withJson("Id: " . $args['id']);
});



$app->run();
```

Ajuste seu código conforme acima ou simplesmente mude o nome da variável $this e veja se resolve seu problema.